# Rails 3.2.17 Runtime Error Redirection Forbidden facebook

Tags: facebook, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2, open-uri

I have this code I use to get avatars from Facebook...

```
if auth.info.image.present?
      user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(auth.info.image))
end
```

When I try to load the code now I get this error:

```
A RuntimeError occurred in authentications#create:

  redirection forbidden: http://graph.facebook.com/672086173/picture?type=square -> https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5.0-1/1086349_672086173_156380036_q.jpg
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:223:in `open_loop'
```

I understand that this is a problem with Open-URI not allowing HTTP to HTTPS redirections... and I understand that this can be solved with Open-Uri-Redirections plugin https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/open_uri_redirections

But there are two things I don't understand:

1. This was working just fine YESTERDAY... and I've changed nothing. So why, suddenly, can Paperclip not get the correct URL?
2. The instructions for Open-Uri-redirections give the following example:

   open('http://github.com', :allow_redirections => :safe)

How would I reconcile this with my code above?

Comment: I'm with the same error, yesterday it was working hahaha

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Update

If you are using `omniauth-facebook` please follow deivid's answer.

Another way to solve this issue is to replace http with https. In that way it will redirect from https to https and you won't get a redirection forbidden error.

Example

```
> url = auth.info.image
=> "http://graph.facebook.com/672086173/picture?type=square"

> avatar_url =url.gsub("­http","htt­ps")
=> "https://graph.facebook.com/672086173/picture?type=square"
```

---

I had the exact same problem. I solve it with following steps

First in your gemfile add

```
gem 'open_uri_redirections'
```

and run  bundle install  to install the gem

And then in your model

```
private

  def process_uri(uri)
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'open_uri_redirections'
    open(uri, :allow_redirections => :safe) do |r|
      r.base_uri.to_s
    end
  end
```

Now process the avatar url with the method like

```
if auth.info.image.present?
   avatar_url = process_uri(auth.info.image)
   user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(avatar_url))
end
```

Hope this helps anyone else that may be having this issue.

Comment: Getting the following error: A Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError occurred in authentications#create:

  No handler found for "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5.0-1/1086349_672086173_156380036_q.jpg"
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/io_adapters/registry.rb:19:in `handler_for'

Comment: This line should be: user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(avatar_url))          NOW it works. :)

Comment: Where does the 'process the avatar url' method go...? should it go in the create block?

Comment: @mysticcola I have a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071386/redirection-forbidden-facebook-paperclip-image)

Comment: For some reason I keep getting a NoMethodError undefined method for process_uri even though it's clearly in my User.rb model. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 43):

I actually think the cleanest way of handling this is directly requesting the avatar through `https`. To do that, just use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/672086173/picture?type=square
```

instead of

```
http://graph.facebook.com/672086173/picture?type=square
```

If you're using `omniauth-facebook`, you'll need to specify `secure_image_url: true` in your omniauth initializer to generate that url. Like so:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "XXXX", "XXXX",
                           image_size: { width: 500, height: 500 },
                           secure_image_url: true
```

Your omniauth initializer should be in your `config/initializers` directory, probably called `omniauth.rb` or `devise.rb` if you're using it together with devise.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if everyone was using omniauth-facebook. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, this is a much cleaner answer, and works like a charm!  Thanks for suggesting that omniauth-facebook setting!

Comment: secure_image_url: true is the way to go.

Comment: Could you detail more where exactly this should go?

Comment: If someone could provide a detailed description of where this configuration should go..

Comment: An example of what you're `config/initializers/devise.rb` file should contain:  `config.omniauth :facebook, "XXXX", "XXXX", image_size: { width: 500, height: 500 }, secure_image_url: true`

Comment: Thanks @flyingL123, I've added your tip to the answer

Answer (score 5):

open_uri_redirections was not working for me.  I could get it working by changing the original facebook image url to https from http.  That way the redirect to the akamai CDN on https is not a http -> https redirect, but a https - https redirect.

in your example

`user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(auth.info.image))`

would become

```
uri = URI.parse(auth.info.image)
uri.scheme = 'https'
user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(uri))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same error. Yesterday it was working. So, i've used the following solution without gem:

```
url = URI.parse('<YOUR FACEBOOK URL>')

h = Net::HTTP.new url.host, url.port
h.use_ssl = url.scheme == 'https'

head = h.start do |u|
  u.head url.path
end

new_url = head['location']
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, @deep's solution wasn't quite working for me, although it did bring me significantly closer.

I ended up doing this:

```
private
    def process_uri(uri)
        require 'open-uri'
        require 'open_uri_redirections'
        open(uri, :allow_redirections => :safe) do |r|
            r.base_uri.to_s
        end
    end
```

And then:

```
avatar_url = process_uri(auth[:info][:image])
new_user.update_attribute(:remote_avatar_url, avatar_url)
```

Comment: A number of people have mentioned that Deep's answer didn't work for them... I can't quite figure out "why" though... What was the error you were getting?  It worked perfect for me the first time... (well... the SECOND time, after I modified his process uri)