# Facebook Omniauth + Carrierwave Profile Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, carrierwave

I have an application which user Devise+Omniauth to allow the users to signup via Facebook. I am also using Carrierwave to allow the users to upload their own profile image and to process the image requested from Facebook. As such, I have the following functions in the controller and user model:

`user.rb`

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth( data, signed_in_resource=nil)
user = User.where(:email => data.info.email).first
unless user
  params =
    {  
      :user =>
      {
        :username => data.uid,
        :email => data.info.email,
        :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
        :user_profile_attributes => 
          {
            :first_name => data.info.first_name,
            :last_name => data.info.last_name,
            :remote_image_url => data.info.image
          },
        :user_auths_attributes =>
        [{
          :uid => data.uid,
          :provider => data.provider
        }]
      }
    }
    user = User.create!(params[:user])
end
return user
end
```

`omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
def facebook
# You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
```

Unfortunately, I keep running into this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: User profile image could not download file: redirection forbidden: http://graph.facebook.com/813865346/picture?type=square -> https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5.0-1/1118622_813865346_1465272585_q.jpg):
app/models/user.rb:68:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `facebook'
```

Where line 68 is `user = User.create!(params[:user])`

Logging the `params[:user]` provides the following values:

```
Params: {:username=>"*", :email=>"*", :password=>"iePVLt7XEWk4YwPjja6n", :user_profile_attributes=>{:first_name=>"*", :last_name=>"*", :remote_image_url=>"http://graph.facebook.com/*/picture?type=square"}, :user_auths_attributes=>{:uid=>"*", :provider=>"facebook"}}
```

I would like some help on getting past this error.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22664100/2300000 you might find it helpful. Its a problem with open uri as by default open uri does not allow redirection. Although you need to re-factor your find_for_facebook_oauth method to get it working. If you have any problems let me know in the comments

Answer (score 27):

I was facing the same problem. It seems that the issue was `http` redirecting to `https`. So I replaced them using `gsub` as follows:

```
user.remote_avatar_url = auth.info.image.gsub('http://','https://')
```

Answer (score 13):

The omniauth-facebook strategy has an option to change the picture url to a secure **https** url.

> secure_image_url: Set to true to use https for the avatar image url
>   returned in the auth hash.

For example, the picture with a secure url would be requested in devise.rb or omniauth.rb this way:

`provider :facebook, 'secrets', 'secrets', :secure_image_url => true`

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answer *Sandeep Laxman*, the problem is `http` must replace with `https`, because is secure image from Facebook, we can use `gsub` #ref [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub)

```
user.remote_avatar_url = auth.info.image.gsub('http:','https:')
```

or use `sub`

```
user.remote_avatar_url = auth.info.image.sub('http:','https:')
```